# Is it possible to use big5 character set in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, internationalization, cjk

A potential client of ours wants to use the big5 character encoding on their new website.

Is it possible to use the Drupal CMS to make a site in big5?

Its possible this questions does not make sense because I don't find many google results with big5 drupal as a keyword...

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it is not possible. Not without hacking core and its database-layer, filtering-layer and form-layer.

Drupal passes all strings around in UTF-8. Big-5 is "included" in UTF-8, meaning: all characters in Big-5 can be found in UTF-8 (and many more).

Comment: Thanks berkes! You're correct about Big-5 being "included" in UTF-8 so the need to shift to "pure" big-5 is not really necessary.

Comment: Also: converting existing code, text or database from Big5 to UTF is not all that hard and well-documented.